# Create more records of same entity at once

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I was looking around for quite a long time, but couldn't find if is possible or how to do it.

My question is: What is best way to create about 500 new records in one entity?

Is there way to create a collection and pass collection to `service.Create(myCollectionOf500)`?
Or there is only simple `for loop` and calling `Create()` method 500 times?

Thanks!

Comment: in general there is `AddRange` method too associated with service, so that can be used, but i think for loop is simple enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Dynamics CRM you have two methods to create a record, the first is with the `Create` method you mentioned in your question, the second is executing a `CreateRequest` message.

If your CRM instance is at least CRM 2011 UR12 you can use `ExecuteMultipleRequest` to execute a batch of requests.

[MSDN: Use ExecuteMultiple to improve performance for bulk data load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/JJ863631.aspx)